# Scientifically plausible powers : part 1

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My creature was capable of creating plasmoid flames from thin air not requiring oxygen and combustible objects similar to this "The user can create, shape, and manipulate plasma fire or fiery plasma. While similar to combustion, there are key differences. It is plasma with the form and properties of fire, and the flames created are powered by the energies that drive the fourth state of matter and are composed of it. Because it is plasma, it does not require oxygen to keep burning."
. what mechanism does it need to produce this effect without violating scientific laws ( like transporting matter ) ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a description of the power in question. You may also want to consider not restricting yourself to what is physically possible in the real world. Pretty much every comic book character is regularly doing impossible things.

Comment: Have you ever turned on a fluorescent lamp? Congratulations! You are a creature which can and did create a "plasmoid flame" from thin gas without requiring oxygen or combustible fuel.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined "plasmoid", so I'm just going to ignore that for now.

To produce flames without oxygen or combustible materials means that your character must produce both. In this case, you would need a character who secretes (under pressure) two hypergolic substances. These would react upon contact with each other and produce a flame.

And don't ask me for recommendations. Hypergolic substances tend to be toxic, corrosive or just plain nasty, so the biochemistry needed to produce them is likely to be, shall we say, unlikely. As a starting point you might look up the bombardier beetle.

Answer (score 1):

### Stupidly strong heating capabilities

According to [this](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/2000-05/957446951.Ph.r.html) to turn air into plasma you need to heat it up to 174,000 degrees centigrade. At that heat you don’t need oxygen or combustible materials, but any oxygen and combustible materials will be set on fire in the vicinity.

Assuming however your creature has perfect energy transfer, you can achieve this for a cubic centimeter of air with about 50 calories according to [this calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/specific-heat). You will have heated the 1.2 milligrams of nitrogen to the needed temperature to be a plasma. A 4 centimeter cube requires more energy than most people need in a day.

Also this assumes that your heat transfer is loss less. This is like setting up a camp fire and expecting it to only heat up you and not your tent or the surroundings. Depending on the range a 10% loss would be mind boggling good, so most likely a single cubic centimeter of plasma will cost 500 calories or more.

Answer (score 1):

## Compression

Probably the easiest way to get a limited plasma is through compression.  The idea gas law says that if you halve the volume of a gas you double it's temperature.  A body temperature 300K becomes 600K(Hot oven) when the volume is halved.  It becomes 3000K when cut to a tenth of the volume(glowing and melting metal)

This has to be done quickly to be adiabatic(No heat transfer, so the creature doesn't cook itself)  What you are looking for would be a conical shaped cavity with a large heavy muscle that slams against it and a plug of water or mucous to keep it contained inertially.  There would likely also be some sort of trigger mechanism to allow the force pushing the muscle to build up.

Bonus points for a flammable liquid or gas in the cavity before hand.

This is essentially how a diesel engine works.

Answer (score 1):

**It makes sparks**

[image: static spark]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkFK7d3KTTM

> However, sparks with very low energy still produce a "plasma tunnel"
> through the air, through which electricity can pass. This plasma is
> heated to temperatures often greater than the surface of the sun, and
> can cause small, localized burns.

Your creature scuffs along the carpet, or carries with it a tolerant cat which it pets vigorously, accumulating static charge.  On touching a grounded object your creature makes a glowing plasma through which the charge equilibrates.  The glowing plasma conduit through the air is a spark.

One does not need access to semidivine energy sources to make plasma with this method.

If the spark is not flamey enough for your purposes consider the corona discharge - same principle but more awesome shapes.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge#Introduction

> A corona discharge is a process by which a current flows from an
> electrode with a high potential into a neutral fluid, usually air, by
> ionizing that fluid so as to create a region of plasma around the
> electrode.

Background reading:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186199/why-do-electric-sparks-appear-blue-purple

Answer (score 0):

**Bluffing**

The creature cannot shoot plasmoid flames. That is scientifically implausible. But the creature's friends are not scientists, so he tells everyone he can shoot flames anyway.

The friends don't 100% believe him. But he is a big guy, and no one wants to be the first one to call his bluff. For the same reason, no one is brave enough to ask what "plasmoid" means.

The origin of this story is the one time he was caught in a wildfire and his mane went ablaze. In order to save face he claimed he put the fire there on purpose. And he can do it again whenever he wants.